# Actionscript 3.0: Save data from an fla file into an .as file

Tags: actionscript-3

Can anyone help me how to save changes of an object from an fla file into a .as file? Say I have an integer which will increment by one if a button is clicked and let's say I clicked it 5 times which would make it's value from zero to five...How can I send this data into my .as file? I already looked on the internet but I got no clear answers...I'm using actionscript 3.

Comment: I have tried tracing the data from my .as file but it would always returns zero (since it's default value is 0 )...

Comment: Please post some code to show us what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should be handling the click and count functionality from your .as file.
**Don't start putting code inside your Library Objects.**   Its a very bad practice
something like this:

```
package  {
    //imports

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var clickCount:int = 0;

        public function Main() 
        {
            yourButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        }

        function clickHandler(event_object:MouseEvent) {
         clickCount++; // increments by 1
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to 'send' data to an .as file give it a property and, from your Main file, set the property of an instance of that Class, eg:

```
package {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    // other imports as necessary
    public class Tracker extends MovieClip {
        private var _numIncrements:int = 0;
        public function Tracker() {

        }
        public function set numIncrements(p_value:int):void {
            _numIncrements = p_value
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in the variable list of your Main class:

```
private var _tracker:Tracker = new Tracker();
```

And in the Main CLICK handler:

```
 _tracker.numIncrements ++;
```